# Can the Arduino-HomeKit-ESP8266 library be used with the WiFi101 library?

Tags: esp8266, home-automation

I am currently trying to create a project to setup a HomeKit remote control to control my smart home devices with the [Arduino-HomeKit-ESP8266 library](https://github.com/Mixiaoxiao/Arduino-HomeKit-ESP8266).

I am currently using a Arduino-based TinyCircuit device with the Atmel ATWINC1500 WiFi module. Is there any solutions available or any way to **modify the code** to make it work with my current WiFi shield, as it uses the [WiFi101 library](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WiFi101) instead of the [WiFi library](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WiFi)?

I am trying to test the "ConnectWithWPA.ino" from the WiFi101 examples with the HomeKit library. The code requires a "pgmspace.h" which I am not too sure what is it for.

ConnectWithWPA.ino:

```
/*

 This example connects to an unencrypted WiFi network.
 Then it prints the  MAC address of the WiFi shield,
 the IP address obtained, and other network details.

 Circuit:
 * WiFi shield attached

 created 13 July 2010
 by dlf (Metodo2 srl)
 modified 31 May 2012
 by Tom Igoe
 */
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFi101.h>
#include <arduino_homekit_server.h> // INSERTED CODE

//access the config defined in C code
#include "arduino_secrets.h" 
///////please enter your sensitive data in the Secret tab/arduino_secrets.h
char ssid[] = SECRET_SSID;        // your network SSID (name)
char pass[] = SECRET_PASS;    // your network password (use for WPA, or use as key for WEP)
int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;     // the WiFi radio's status

extern "C" homekit_server_config_t config; // INSERTED CODE

void setup() {
  //Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }

  // check for the presence of the shield:
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_SHIELD) {
    Serial.println("WiFi shield not present");
    // don't continue:
    while (true);
  }

  // attempt to connect to WiFi network:
  while ( status != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to WPA SSID: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network:
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);

    // wait 10 seconds for connection:
    delay(10000);
  }

  // you're connected now, so print out the data:
  Serial.print("You're connected to the network");
  printCurrentNet();
  printWiFiData();


  arduino_homekit_setup(&config); // INSERTED CODE
}

void loop() {
  // check the network connection once every 10 seconds:
  delay(10000);
  printCurrentNet();

  arduino_homekit_loop(); // INSERTED CODE
}

void printWiFiData() {
  // print your WiFi shield's IP address:
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.print("IP A'ddress: ");
  Serial.println(ip);
  Serial.println(ip);

  // print your MAC address:
  byte mac[6];
  WiFi.macAddress(mac);
  Serial.print("MAC address: ");
  printMacAddress(mac);

}

void printCurrentNet() {
  // print the SSID of the network you're attached to:
  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());

  // print the MAC address of the router you're attached to:
  byte bssid[6];
  WiFi.BSSID(bssid);
  Serial.print("BSSID: ");
  printMacAddress(bssid);

  // print the received signal strength:
  long rssi = WiFi.RSSI();
  Serial.print("signal strength (RSSI):");
  Serial.println(rssi);

  // print the encryption type:
  byte encryption = WiFi.encryptionType();
  Serial.print("Encryption Type:");
  Serial.println(encryption, HEX);
  Serial.println();
}

void printMacAddress(byte mac[]) {
  for (int i = 5; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (mac[i] < 16) {
      Serial.print("0");
    }
    Serial.print(mac[i], HEX);
    if (i > 0) {
      Serial.print(":");
    }
  }
  Serial.println();
}
```

It produced this error when verifying:

```
Alternatives for osapi.h: []
ResolveLibrary(osapi.h)
  -> candidates: []
In file included from libraries\HomeKit-ESP8266\src/wolfssl/wolfcrypt/settings.h:171:0,
from \libraries\HomeKit-ESP8266\src/wolfssl/wolfcrypt/types.h:27,
from \libraries\HomeKit-ESP8266\src/wolfssl/wolfcrypt/ed25519.h:26,
from \libraries\HomeKit-ESP8266\src/crypto.h:12,
from \libraries\HomeKit-ESP8266\src/arduino_homekit_server.h:15,
from \ConnectWithWPA.ino:17:
\libraries\HomeKit-ESP8266\src/user_settings.h:15:10: fatal error: osapi.h: No such file or directory
 #include "osapi.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

After adding [osapi.h](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/tools/sdk/include/osapi.h) into the HomeKit src folder.

```
Alternatives for user_config.h: []
ResolveLibrary(user_config.h)
  -> candidates: []
In file included from \libraries\HomeKit-ESP8266\src/user_settings.h:15:0,
                 from \libraries\HomeKit-ESP8266\src/wolfssl/wolfcrypt/settings.h:171,
                 from \libraries\HomeKit-ESP8266\src/wolfssl/wolfcrypt/types.h:27,
                 from \libraries\HomeKit-ESP8266\src/wolfssl/wolfcrypt/ed25519.h:26,
                 from \libraries\HomeKit-ESP8266\src/crypto.h:12,
                 from \libraries\HomeKit-ESP8266\src/arduino_homekit_server.h:15,
                 from \ConnectWithWPA.ino:17:

\libraries\HomeKit-ESP8266\src/osapi.h:29:10: fatal error: user_config.h: No such file or directory
 #include "user_config.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

After adding one example of [user_config.h](https://github.com/pubnub/ESP8266/blob/master/include/user_config.h) into the HomeKit src folder.

```
Alternatives for pgmspace.h: []
ResolveLibrary(pgmspace.h)
  -> candidates: []
In file included from \libraries\HomeKit-ESP8266\src/homekit_debug.h:12:0,
                 from \libraries\HomeKit-ESP8266\src/user_settings.h:16,
                 from \libraries\HomeKit-ESP8266\src/wolfssl/wolfcrypt/settings.h:171,
                 from \libraries\HomeKit-ESP8266\src/wolfssl/wolfcrypt/types.h:27,
                 from \libraries\HomeKit-ESP8266\src/wolfssl/wolfcrypt/ed25519.h:26,
                 from \libraries\HomeKit-ESP8266\src/crypto.h:12,
                 from \libraries\HomeKit-ESP8266\src/arduino_homekit_server.h:15,
                 from \ConnectWithWPA.ino:17:
\libraries\HomeKit-ESP8266\src/esp_xpgm.h:15:10: fatal error: pgmspace.h: No such file or directory
 #include <pgmspace.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

My TinyCircuit uses these components:

- TINYZERO PROCESSOR BOARD
- TINYSCREEN OLED TINYSHIELD
- [WIFI TINYSHIELD (ATWINC1500)](https://tinycircuits.com/collections/communication/products/wifi-tinyshield-atwinc1500)
- Lithium Ion Polymer battery - 3.7V 150MAH

Comment: you can't use it.